# When I implement database mirroring in SQL server it shows an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[image: When i click the start mirroring button it shows the below error message. When I try to connect the mirror and witness server through management studio it's connecting and working fine]

When I click the start mirroring button it shows the below error message. When I try to connect the mirror and witness server through management studio it's connecting and working fine.the user i am logging to the machine is with the domain user

Comment: Did you specify port numbers appropriately? I can't tell as you blanked them out.  Also, i assume you created endpoints first.  Also specify if all three are same server or different server.

Comment: yes we specified port numbers and also we created endpoint too.witness server and mirror server in same machine and principal server in another.